# Checking character value in a loop

Tags: java

```
package Medium;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println("please input a num:");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = in.nextInt();
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i =0;i<=num;i++){
            String s = Integer.toString(i);         //get all the numbers changed into String type
            arr.add(i, s);
            //System.out.println(arr);
        }

        for(int j=0;j<arr.size();j++){
            String t = arr.get(j);
            System.out.println(t+"----------");
            for(int k =0;k<t.length();k++){         //go through all the nums
                System.out.println(t.charAt(k));
                if(t.charAt(k)==(char)(1)){         //this line may possible be wrong?
                    sum = sum+1;//none of the sum be added
                    System.out.println("sum:"+sum);
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(sum);    
        }
    }
}
```

input 11,the outcome is:

```
please input a num:
11
0----------
0
1----------
1
2----------
2
3----------
3
4----------
4
5----------
5
6----------
6
7----------
7
8----------
8
9----------
9
10----------
1
11----------
1
0
```

the description is: Count the number of k's between 0 and n. k can be 0 - 9.

none of the `sum` is being used, why is that?
I though it may probably come up for `if(t.charAt(k) == (char)(1))`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Count the number of times 1 appears in a list of numbers between 0 and the given "num"? (So 11 adds 2, 21 adds one, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You are right.

```
if(t.charAt(k)==(char)(1)){
```

must be

```
if(t.charAt(k)=='1'){
```

`(char)(1)` is the character at posion one in the charset, not the number 1 as character.

You see the difference if you test it in a program with:

```
System.out.println((char)(1));
System.out.println('1');
```

or you can see it using the hex code:

```
System.out.println(String.format("Hex code of (char)1 %04x", (int) (char)1));
System.out.println(String.format("Hex code of '1' %04x", (int) '1'));
```

Output is

```
Hex code of (char)1 0001
Hex code of '1' 0031
```

Comment: thank you.but what's wrong with if(t.charAt(k)==(char)(1)),however?